# What are bounties and blood shards?

Tags: diablo-iii

I was changing the difficulty for Diablo 3 when I saw these details:

[image]

What are bounties and blood shards for? I must have missed some kind of update that tells me what this is all about.

Comment: These might be an expansion only feature. Bounties are quests offered to go out into the wilderness and kill a specific target, but I don't know if its implemented.

Comment: I believe both are part of Adventure Mode (expansion content). But might show up in ActV or during 61+ leveling (still expansion content).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have **RotS** expansion you can play in **adventure mode**.
When you start the game with these options you will be given **25 random bounties** scattered around all 5 towns(5 for each).

These bounties will be simple randomly generated tasks like killing a certain boss or champion monster,clearing whole area from monsters,certain dungeon dungeon or event...
Which is a fun way to break the monotony of standard quests you got fed up with.

Upon completing a bounty you will be rewarded with gold,experience,horadric cache(drops random loot when used) and **blood shards**.For completing all 5 bounties in single act,you will get greater horadric cache and chance of Rift Keystone.

**Blood Shards** are used for **gambling**(buying unidentified items) from Kadala.
And to buy greater horadric caches from Lorath Nahr(not sure if they changed this).